# SharePoint get ContentType Name

Tags: c#, sharepoint, splistitem

I am trying to get All Folders and Files from a **SharePoint** library, executing a single Request.

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll' />";
var libraryName = "Specific Documents";

ListItemCollection itemsRaw = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName).GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(itemsRaw);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This code works well, and as result I have a list of All Folders and Files within the specified library.

It seems that the files details are loaded in a lazy manner. Only the first level from details hierarchy. But I don't know how, the **FieldValues** collection is filled with Data.

[image: ListItem details]

I see that the `ListItem ContentType.Name` is not initialized.

[image: ContentType Name is not initialized]

Is it possible somehow to update the query in a manner which will load the data for **ContentType** in this single call.

Or the only possibility is to iterate through all files and do a load of ContentType for the specific file?

I did this in the following way:

```
foreach(var listItem in listItemCollection)
{
    context.Load(listItem, k => k.ContentType);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    var contentTypeName = listItem.ContentType.Name;
}
```

But I am going to get this information in a single call, If it is possible, without iterating in the collection and starting multiple calls to **ClientContext**.

*P.S.: I am new to **SharePoint** programming. I just want to fix a bug.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you correctly noticed in SharePoint Client Side Object Model (CSOM) [ClientRuntimeContext.Load Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536388(v=office.14).aspx) does not retrieve all the properties for client object.

[ClientRuntimeContext.Load Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536388(v=office.14).aspx) has the following syntax:

```
public void Load<T>(
    T clientObject,
    params Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] retrievals
)
where T : ClientObject
```

where `retrievals` parameter is intended for specifying properties that have to be retrieved.

Secondly, since SharePoint CSOM supports [Request Batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx), your example could be modified to this one:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    ctx.Load(item, i => i.ContentType);
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

> Note: request is submitted to the server only once in this example

But still the provided example requires two requests to the server:

- retrieve list items
- retrieve content type for list items

and it could be *improved* from performance perspective by reducing requests  to the server till one.

**Final example**

The example demonstrates how to retrieve list items and specify explicitly which properties to retrieve:

```
 var listTitle = "Documents";
 var query = new CamlQuery();
 query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll' />";

 var items = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle).GetItems(query);
 ctx.Load(items,icol => icol.Include(
                i => i.ContentType,
                i => i.FieldValues));
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim, for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The final example does not work (in SP2010).

There is an exception "The query expression is not supported"
If you explicitly states all required fields then the solution below works.

```
var listTitle = "Documents";
var query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll' />";

var items = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle).GetItems(query);

string[] fieldsToMigrate = new string[] { "Title", "FieldA", "FieldB" };
ctx.Load(items, a => a.Include(b => b.ContentType, b => b["FileRef"]));
foreach (var f in fieldsToLoad) {
    ctx.Load(items, includes => includes.Include(a => a[f]));
}

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```